# Reading a file into a multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader, filereader

I want to read in a grid of numbers (n*n) from a file and copy them into a multidimensional array, one int at a time. I have the code to read in the file and print it out, but dont know how to take each int. I think i need to splitstring method and a blank delimiter "" in order to take every charcter, but after that im not sure. I would also like to change blank characters to 0, but that can wait!

This is what i have got so far, although it doesnt work.

```
        while (count <81  && (s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
        count++;

        String[] splitStr = s.split("");
        String first = splitStr[number];
        System.out.println(s);
        number++;

        }
    fr.close();
    }
```

A sample file is like this(the spaces are needed):

```
26     84
 897 426 
  4   7  
   492   
4       5
   158   
  6   5  
 325 169 
95     31
```

Basically i know how to read in the file and print it out, but dont know how to take the data from the reader and put it in a multidimensional array.

I have just tried this, but it says 'cannot covernt from String[] to String'

```
        while (count <81  && (s = br.readLine()) != null)
    {       
    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<9; j++)
            grid[i][j] = s.split("");

    }
```

Comment: You should give more information than "it doesn't work."  Was there a compile error?  A runtime exception?  It didn't output what you thought it would?  How does your program's behaviour differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: sample of file would be better

Comment: Do you have to use a BufferedReader or could you use a Scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your file this is how I would do it:

```
Lint<int[]> ret = new ArrayList<int[]>();

Scanner fIn = new Scanner(new File("pathToFile"));
while (fIn.hasNextLine()) {
    // read a line, and turn it into the characters
    String[] oneLine = fIn.nextLine().split("");
    int[] intLine = new int[oneLine.length()];
    // we turn the characters into ints
    for(int i =0; i < intLine.length; i++){
        if (oneLine[i].trim().equals(""))
            intLine[i] = 0;
        else
            intLine[i] = Integer.parseInt(oneLine[i].trim());
    }
    // and then add the int[] to our output
    ret.add(intLine):
}
```

At the end of this code, you will have a list of `int[]` which can be easily turned into an `int[][]`.

Comment: Thanks. For the lines       int[] intLine = new int[oneLine.length()];
      for(int i =0; i < intLine.length(); i++){ it says 'cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]' how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: oops, remove the parentheses. It should be `intLine.length`

Comment: Ah, i previously did that and got the error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "'         Sorry for being a pain

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: You just updated your post to include a sample input file, so the following won't work as-is for your case.  However, the principle is the same -- tokenize the line you read based on whatever delimiter you want (spaces in your case) then add each token to the columns of a row.**

You didn't include a sample input file, so I'll make a few basic assumptions.

Assuming that the first line of your input file is "n", and the remainder is the n x n integers you want to read, you need to do something like the following:

```
public static int[][] parseInput(final String fileName) throws Exception {
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

 int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
 int[][] result = new int[n][n];

 String line;
 int i = 0;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
  }

  i++;
 }

 return result;
}
```

In this case, an example input file would be:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

which would result in a 3 x 3 array with:

```
row 1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
row 2 = { 4, 5, 6 }
row 3 = { 7, 8, 9 }
```

If your input file doesn't have "n" as the first line, then you can just wait to initialize your final array until you've counted the tokens on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[][] readMatrix(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    List<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (String s = br.readLine(); s != null; s = br.readLine()) {
        String items[] = s.split(" ");
        int[] row = new int[items.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            row[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }
    return rows.toArray(new int[rows.size()][]);
}
```