# Java: Import array from file to array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have files which contains array's like this:
Here is a snippet from one of my .txt

```
itemlist= new int[][] {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
    { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
    { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, 
    { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
};
```

As you see the .txt file contains a multidimensional array list. Is there any way to transfter this to an array within java?

Cheers!

Comment: So the content of your file is essentially java source code?

Comment: Yes,there is a way. What have you tried though?

Comment: yup file  = source but I think i can modify it somehow

Comment: @kg I got the text in a String, then I tried doing some index of but well i fail at importing it as a multiodimeansonal array

Comment: Here's something to get you started : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968859/reading-a-file-into-a-multidimensional-array . Try something, post some code, then maybe you can get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is some kind of homework, so I can't give you code, but if I were you I would:

1) put text from file into one String (without new line marks)

2) (I assume `one file` == `one table data`) try to isolate text between first `{` and last `}` (again regex can help)

3) split content from point 2 to have data from each `{` `}` in separate places (use split and again regex)

4) estimate sizes of array by counting pairs of `{` `}` and counting `,` inside them (by regex, or by iterating chars)

5) now I can create table (I know sizes)

6) in point 3 I isolated all rows (or cols, depends on how you will put them in table) so now it is time to read them and put in table, so we need to iterate via all data from point 3 and:

6.1) drop `{` `}` brackets

6.2) split using `,`

6.3) trim spaces

6.4) parse to Integer and put into array

Hope that is enough to create code.

Comment: Thanks, im at regex part but it wont find { } brackets.. :(

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN What have you tried? Maybe [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) will hepl you a little (entire site is great, not just this part)

Comment: pattern \\{([^}]*)\\}; works but it get no matches because i have new lines \n

Comment: you can replace all new line sign for example `"line1\nline2\nline3".replaceAll("\\n", " ")` but this will give you new String so you have to store it somehow

Comment: then, maybe your pattern is wrong, you can try regex [here](http://regexpal.com/) it is JS regex so it can be slightly different then Java regex mechanism

Comment: I've said too much already. Your problem is not as hard as you may think. All I can say is "do not give up" and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int itemlist[][]= new int[][] {
      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
      { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
      { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, 
      { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
    };

    int length=itemlist.clone().length*itemlist.length;
    int tab[]=new int[length];
    int i=1;
    for(int j=0;j<itemlist.length;j++) 
    {
      for(int k=0;k<itemlist.clone().length;k++)
      {
         tab[i]=itemlist[j][k];
         i++;

         if (i== length) break ;
      }
    }

    for(int h=0;h<length;h++){
      System.out.println(" "+tab[h]);
    }
}
```